# Closing Qt console application terminates process inside exec() call and doesn't reach to scope out from main()

Tags: c++, qt

it is the problem I have in my `Qt` console application:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    MyApp app;
    app.start();

    return a.exec();
} // <== MyApp destructor must be called to free up resourcs but not reach here
```

Qt version: `5.4.1`

Platform: `Windows 10`

Already I have faced with this problem in `Window 7` and not fixing this.

Problem is `exec` call terminates process using `exit` system call in Windows after exiting main event loop and doesn't return.

another soultions such as using `aboutToQuit` signal of `QCoreApplication` class not working.

Comment: Set breakpoint on exception throwing.

Comment: @AnatolyS examined and doesn't working.

Comment: What is your MyApp? What is MyApp inherited from?

Comment: `MyApp` is my application starter, it's not the matter what it is, you can assume that was a simple class have a `destructor` and you want to call destrcutor when scope out from main function to free up resources.

Comment: Just for reproducing the problem what version of Qt do you use?

Comment: @AnatolyS Qt version: 5.4.1

Answer (score 1):

Straight from [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#exec):

> We recommend that you connect clean-up code to the aboutToQuit() signal, instead of putting it in your application's main() function because on some platforms the exec() call may not return. For example, **on Windows when the user logs off, the system terminates the process after Qt closes all top-level windows. Hence, there is no guarantee that the application will have time to exit its event loop and execute code at the end of the main() function after the exec() call**.

You say you tried `aboutToQuit()` with no luck but you should definitely focus on making that work. Would you please update the pasted code to include the aboutToQuit attempt so that we can help you?